# How to calculate difference between sparse histogram in Python

Tags: python, histogram

I am using 3D histogram to compare a superpixel region in two images taken from a video sequence. Based on histogram threshold, I want to classify regions as similar or dissimilar.
I was using chi square distance to compare the two histograms. But I saw that chi square distance should be used only for dense histograms.
My histogram is sparse with a lot of bins containing zero entries.
Can you suggest me the best way to compare these histograms in Python?

Comment: Why can't chi² distance be computed for sparse histograms?

Comment: I am not sure about it. I read somewhere that is should be used for dense histograms.

Comment: It seems that the openCV function of calculating chi square difference neglects the bins having zero value. It uses the defnition mentioned [**here**](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html)
But I don't want to neglect the bins having zero values, so I dont believe it gives the correct difference.

Comment: I have done plenty of test, more sparse is the matrix and more this way of doing is close to the real result, but as you guessed, it s not the correct result, just an approx.